# Desktop entry runs but terminal closes immediately and launcher never runs

Tags: java, desktop-application, executable-jar, gnome, ubuntu-21.04

Trying to setup a desktop entry on ubuntu 21.04 for a .jar file. When I execute it manually with:

```
$ java -jar /home/usr/Documents/launcher.jar
```

It outputs some logs from the jar and seems to throw that process into the background.
So as long as the terminal is open it stays running.
But when I setup the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon=/home/usr/Pictures/logos/launcher.png
Exec=java -jar "/home/usr/Documents/launcher.jar"
Name=Launcher
Comment=Launcher information here
```

And when I run it a terminal opens showing the logs as expected but then it just closes immediately after and the launcher never actually starts. I was able to take a screenshot of the terminal before it closed/exited and there was no errors or unexpected logging.

UPDATE 1:
I tried to see if running it manually with following command gave the same output and running it as a desktop app and it did. Failed to actually launch `launcher.jar`

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "java -jar /home/usr/Documents/launcher.jar"
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to use `nohup` command?

Add it before your java command and redirect outputs:

`nohup java -jar [...] > launcher.log 2>&1 &`